# Simulating a Power Amplifier in MATLAB using "lsim"

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink block with noise as input and a filter to get colored noise, the block also consist a power amplifier to amplify the output.

> noise --> digital filter --> colored noise --> power amplifier --> desired output

My problem is that filter is digital and the transfer function can be defined using `filt` command, however there is no specific way to describe **power amplifier** and I thought of breaking the **power amplifier** in to sub blocks and combining as a sys using control toolbox of MATLAB.

1. Should I use `s-plan` or `z-plan` (since power amplifier is not digital in my opinion but the input to the amplifier is coming from the digital filter sampled at a rate)
2. Is this approach reasonable at all or should I look for something else?
3. One major problem I face is the fact that at the end of the power amplifier block there is a math function (sqrt), when ever I try to take the laplace transform I get a result `pi^(1/2)/2*s^(3/2)` and for z-transform it is not calculating any value instead the result looks like  `ztrans(n^(1/2), n, z)`

My Code:

```
[result1, time_out1]=lsim(sys,u,t); %result1 output of the filter

   num_math2 = [2]
   den_math2 = [1 0 0 0]

   tf_sqr = tf(num_math2, den_math2); 

   num_gain = [1]
   den_gain = [1000 0 0 ]
   tf_gain = tf(num_gain, den_gain)

   s1 = series(tf_sqr, tf_gain)

   num_gain_f = [9999]
   den_gain_f = [10000 0 0 ] 

   tf_feedgain = tf(num_gain_f, den_gain_f)
   tf_delay = tf([1], [1 0])
   tf_g = series(tf_feedgain,tf_delay)

   %tf_g_1 = ss(tf_g);

   s2 = feedback(1,tf_g);
   s3 = series (s1,s2);

   %s_final = series(sys,s3);

   [result, time_out]= lsim(s3,result1,t) %power amp lsim
}
```